# Unable to render php files in browser

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp

I am very new to php, and I am trying to develop a facebook application using php. 
I am using Joyent as my hosting platform.

Currently, 
I am trying to do some simple scripts in php and then build on them. However I am unable to see any php files being rendered properly in my application.

For eg:
I have a simple script called phpinfo.php:

If I execute this on terminal like php phpinfo.php , I can see all the configurations. 
However if I try to access the same file as http://xxxxxx.facebook.joyent.us/phpinfo.php, I get :
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Even if I rename this file to index.php its still the same. However I am able to access other html files [index.html] on the same location .

These are some of my php settings:
These are some of the settings:

```
[fbkusoni:~/web/public] aafhe7vh$ php phpinfo.php | grep On
allow_url_fopen => On => On
auto_globals_jit => On => On
enable_dl => On => On
file_uploads => On => On
ignore_repeated_errors => On => On
ignore_repeated_source => On => On
implicit_flush => On => On
log_errors => On => On
register_argc_argv => On => On
report_memleaks => On => On
y2k_compliance => On => On
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) backtrack check => On
mysql.allow_persistent => On => On
session.bug_compat_warn => On => On
session.use_cookies => On => On
suhosin.cookie.cryptdocroot => On => On
suhosin.cookie.cryptua => On => On
suhosin.mt_srand.ignore => On => On
suhosin.protectkey => On => On
suhosin.server.encode => On => On
suhosin.server.strip => On => On
suhosin.session.cryptdocroot => On => On
suhosin.session.cryptua => On => On
suhosin.session.encrypt => On => On
suhosin.srand.ignore => On => On
suhosin.stealth => On => On
```

The answer might be very naive, but I am just trying to get started and looking for any suggestions regarding this and also using Joyent and cakephp to develop facebook applications.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe your host isn't configured properly for php use?

Comment: You might want to edit your question to tidy up the display of code. That would make it easier to read. Use the `101010` button.

Comment: i think i should see the 101010 button after selcting the code as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122890/how-to-format-source-code-in-stackoverflow-closed

I am not able to locate it .. I am using firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your script executable (`chmod +x phpinfo.php`)?

What does the web server error log say?

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for the reply
Yes the script is executable. 
I am trying to search for error logs on the virtual console on the servers :), Any specific place I should look for logs if someone has used Joyent before.http://www.joyent.com/

Comment: Hi Pete, 
I was able to see the logs , I change the error_log parameter to write it to a file. 

These are the errors:
PHP Warning:  [eAccelerator] Can not create shared memory area in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Unable to start eAccelerator module in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  [eAccelerator] Can not create shared memory area in Unknown on line 0

I am trying to look if this is Joyent specific issue. Do you know which file is it referring to when it says line 0?

Comment: I found out that this is related to shared memory size being too small by default. eaccelerator.net/wiki/Faq  Interestingly I dont have this file /etc/sysctl.conf Should I be looking at any other location or just create one there ?

Comment: It turns out that eAccelerator won't work properly at all on Joyent's stack. They use FastCGI based PHP managed by mod_fcgid, and that's not a situation that any PHP cache can provide any benefit in.
For the benefit of anyone hitting the same problem, just remove eaccelerator.so from your php.ini file completely

Answer (score 0):

PHP may not be installed as an Apache module correctly.  You can run it on the command line because that's in CGI mode & doesn't need Apache.  Run apachectl configtest to see if there's anything wrong with the Apache configuration.

Comment: Hi Pickle, 

Thnks 4 reply. 
I executed the command:
> apachectl configtest
httpd: Syntax error on line 2 of /opt/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf: Could not open configuration

The file looks like
cat /opt/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf
# There are things to set in core.conf
Include /opt/local/etc/httpd/includes/core.conf
# There is no reason to touch pid.conf
Include /opt/local/etc/httpd/includes/pid.conf

On Joyent servers I do nt have access 2 /opt/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf ; I ll try 2 figure out a way 2 edit the files if thats the prblm. 

Also is there a way 2 post larger comment on this forum?

Answer (score 0):

> Internal Server Error The server
>   encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to
>   complete your request.

This may indicate a syntax error in your code.
Try doing a `php -l <filename>` from the command line for each of your scipt files to verify that they don't contain any syntax errors

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I confirmed there are no errors. Infact since I am able to execute it on terminal might indicate that syntactically it is correct.